# Iterable error with int when using for / argument ()error while using map. Where am i going worng

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried bith ways using map nad using for loop but its not working i know for for loop it has to list,tuples or string. So how do i make this work

## 1

```
def narcissistic(value):
  x = ((value)== sum((c)**len(value) for c in list(value)))
  return x
```

## 2

```
def narcissistic(value):
   x=(value== (map(lambda c :sum(c**len(value)),value)))
   return x
```

Comment: Is `value` a string representation of a number, or an actual number? Python doesn't treat `"123"` the same as `123` (like for instance Javascript does). If it's a string (and the `c` values are thus its digits), you need to convert them back to numbers before you can do mathematical operations on them, like `c**len(value)`. If it's a number to start with, you'd also need to convert it to a string in order to iterate on its digits (as characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes down to confusion about the type of your different objects. Python is a strongly typed language, so each object has a clear type at any given moment and the language generally won't convert anything to another type automatically for you.

Based on the error you're getting, you're calling your function with an `int` argument. This causes you trouble when you try to call `len` or iterate on your `value`. Python `int`s don't have a length, nor are they iterable, so it's quite understandable that these fail under the circumstances.

What you want to do is create a string representation of your `value` number. Then you can loop over the characters of the string, and take its `len` freely.

There's another issue though. You're also trying to do an exponential operation on the `c` variable in the generator expression. That won't work because `c` is a string, not a number. It's a one-digit string, but still a `str` instance! To do math with it, you need to convert it back to a number with `int`.

Here's a fixed version of your function:

```
def narcissistic(number):
    num_str = str(number)
    return sum(int(c)**len(num_str) for c in num_str) == number
```

I've renamed the very generic `value` name with `number`, which should hopefully make it more clear what type each thing is.

Comment: Blckknght :) i really appreciate your efforts to for such explanation i tried changing int to string  after you check comment and  but i did miss changing 'c' to int which was again throwing error. Best thing is i was down with this but now i just corrected that and it helps me keep going. I appreciate again :) :) thank you